# Continuing the same activity when user clicks on Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

i am making an application in which Broadcast listener is starting an activity and notification is displayed.
when a user clicks on home button it goes to the home screen.
But if user clicks on Notification icon then activity state is lost :( .

Please help me how to continue with my activity when user clicks on notification.

Comment: So are you talking about the notification when the user selects a notification and going back to their previous activity?

Comment: yes Heinrik....kindly help me :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't display a notification if the application that is doing the notifying is in the foreground; I just update the UI of the activity and let it be self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent resultIntent = this.getIntent();
```

It gets the started intent from main activity. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an alert dialog for notifications link [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) This will keep your notification on the same screen and in the same activity.

If you want to keep any information when you press home you may use android storage for that and here is the link for [that.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) Storage will be  able to hold data that you need from other activity classes.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks heinrik....i am using status bar notification....i cant use data base as there are lot of data

Answer (score 0):

When building your `Intent` for the `PendingIntent` you send with the notification, add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

If the activity is already on the history stack, it will be resumed and a call to `onNewIntent()` will be triggered. If it's not, the activity will be started with a blank slate.

Comment: where i need to define onNewIntent()

Comment: @Jasra In the Activity that's being resumed. If you're not passing any new data, then you don't need to implement that method.

Comment: as i have said i need to pass values from broadcast receiver to activity...as soon as i press notification icon the activity is restarted

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME
```